# Is it possible to create a web component anyone can use without installation?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, custom-element

I'm just getting started with web components, and if I understand correctly, the point is for them to be reusable by anyone. Is it possible to create a component that can be used by anyone simply by adding a piece of html to their static site (similar to how JavaScript widgets are added, simply by copy-pasting a few lines of code), or does it need to be installed by someone? Or is this not an intended use case of web components?

Comment: you can check angular elements but for that you will need the compiled file

Comment: Web component is a js file. It is not used with installation. Can just be added to script file as a normal js file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. A Web Component is a kind of "Javascript widget".

Typicially, you define a Web Component in a Javascript file.
You can then include it in any HTML with a `<script>` element.

Example with a minimal custom element called `<hello-world>`:

In **hello-world.js**:

```
customElements.define( 'hello-world', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow( {mode: 'open' })
            .innerHTML = 'Hello World!'
    }
} )
```

In your main page **index.html**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- import the web component -->
        <script src="hello-world.js">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- use the new element -->
        <hello-world></hello-world>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: alternately, one could also copy-paste the Javascript code that defines the custom element to its main HTML page.

Comment: It's a nice example.